# Smart Javascript suggestions inside HTML files no loger working after Visual Studio Code update

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I have been using Visual Studio Code for a few months now. I got used to the smart suggestions inside `<script>` elements when writing Javascript inside an HTML file. E.g.

```
<body>
...
<script>/* Suggestions would appear here */</script>
</body>
```

But after a recent update, I no longer get those suggestions inside HTML files (I think they are called **IntelliSense**).

I ran a few searches on Google, and I checked my VSCode workspace settings, but I can't figure out how to get them back. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I've just started using vs code for html files with inline javascript and was wondering if was even possible...

Comment: @PeterBons, yes, it was working great for me until a few days ago; until after a recent update.

Comment: It appears that currently this feature is no longer supported since the adoption of Salsa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CURRENTLY UNSUPPORTED

[JS intellisense doesnt work in HTML script tag VSCode Issue #4369](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4369)

[How to enable Intellisense for JavaScript in Visual Studio Code - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055382/how-to-enable-intellisense-for-javascript-in-visual-studio-code)