# How can I enable IntelliSense for JavaScript inside HTML?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I want to use VS Code to try out the examples of a JavaScript book, but there's no IntelliSense, or at least I don't know how to activate it.

In Visual Studio this feature works out of the box :

[image]

But in VS Code, all I got is a message saying "No suggestions."

[image]

What do I need to do to enable IntelliSense in VS Code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Currently Unsupported

[JS intellisense doesnt work in HTML script tag - VSCode GitHub Issues #4369](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4369)

[Smart Javascript suggestions inside HTML files no loger working after Visual Studio Code update - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039910/smart-javascript-suggestions-inside-html-files-no-loger-working-after-visual-stu)

Comment: sad but it's true :(

Comment: It's supported from version 1.8, please see my answer below.

Comment: @Axel: not sad, and not true — see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/69037585/191246

Answer (score 8):

Starting with the November 2016 (version 1.8) release, Visual Studio Code now fully supports IntelliSense for [JavaScript in HTML](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_javascript-language-support-in-html).

Note that the language support doesn't follow script includes, it only knows about definitions made in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me, when the file had a .js extension. I didn't get any intellisense when I pasted it into .html file between script tags.

Edit To Add: You can also change the Language Mode by clicking 'HTML' in the bottom of the VS Code window and change it to 'JavaScript'.

Comment: That's not a working solution for me. Should be able to have both html and javascript intellisense in one file, as for html files this is fairly common.

Comment: It appears that currently this feature is no longer supported since the adoption of Salsa.

Answer (score 2):

### It ***is*** supported!

Intellisense and syntax highlighting start working after replacing

```html
<script>something()</script>
```

with

```html
<script type="text/javascript">something()</script>
```

Comment: Simple and easy. Best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have HTML language mode selected in the bottom right corner. I had Markdown mode set for an unknown reason (autodetect?) and it didn't work for me. Javascript mode won't work either for HTML files.

[image: HTML language mode selected]

Answer (score -5):

Visual Studio Code version 1.4.0 does not support CSS intelli-sense.

I have an extension for CSS style, id and class intelli-sense for html documents:

Features:

- Style tag completion and hover.
- Style attribute completion and hover.
- Id attribute completion.
- Class attribute completion.
- Scans workspace folder for css files.
- Supports optional resource.json file for fine tuned resource selection.

Link:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css

Comment: At least understand the question before self-promoting.