# Visual Studio autocomplete not working for javascript / css on html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm trying out `visual studio` code editor with `html`, `css`, and `javascript`. I noticed when typing any styles or scripts in the head of the html, autocomplete is failing.

Is anyone else noticing this or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Code then read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055382/how-to-enable-intellisense-for-javascript-in-visual-studio-code).

If your using "regular" VS then most likely you're missing the **Microsoft Web Developer Tools** to your visual studio installation.

One way to add it is to go to programs and features on your OS and click on repair your visual studio
installation. Then on the "Optional features to install" dialog, check the "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" option and complete the repair.