# How to use code completion from multiple add-ons in a single page?

Tags: coldfusion, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I would like to use code completion from multiple add-ons on a single page. i.e. Use code completion for ColdFusion, HTML and CSS on a single .cfm page. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Yeah, it does not sound like it. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42665678/104223) suggests support for multiple languages in one file is possible somehow (i.e. JS and HTML with some limitations), but it is not through multiple add-ons per se. I suspect you would have to write your own (single) extension for that functionality.