# How to enable JSX intellisense in HTML <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, intellisense

I want JSX Intellisense in Visual Studio Code in HTML files, right inside the `<script>` tag. Currently, I can't figure out a way to do so.

Here's my HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Working with forms - Project 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
   function App() {
      return <React.Fragment>
         <h1>Working with forms - Project 2</h1>
      </React.Fragment>
   }

   ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable IntelliSense for JavaScript inside HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055382/how-can-i-enable-intellisense-for-javascript-inside-html)

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: There was an updated answer below the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42665678/522330

Comment: Yeah, that is for JavaScript. I have that. What I am trying to ask help for is JSX.

Comment: ***intellisense*** inside HTML files in VS Code just seems to work for me, I have no special plugins or settings.

Comment: It works for me as well @Keith but the thing is I want it for JSX.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean ***JSX*** is working for me.  eg, if say I created a simple JSX function -> `function X({value}) {}`, and then inside the `React.Fragment` I type `<X` I will get ***intellisense*** for `value`..

Comment: In my case, it doesn't so there must be some setting that does this thing.

Comment: In the same boat. I would _love_ to use babel standalone to do quick TSX component prototypes, but it's not a timesaver if intellisense doens't work.