# Can't get the correct Language Mode / IntelliSense for a script tag with type="text/jsx" in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, babeljs, jsx

I have the latest version of Visual Studio Code (1.75.1). Am using "Solarized Dark" color theme.

I have an html file, with React Javascript code inside  tags.

If I leave the language selection as "HTML" it doesn't color anything inside the script tags:
[image]

If I use "JavaScript React" or "Babel Javascript" as the language mode I get error highlights that are not errors, and intellisense doesn't work that well:
[image]

I tried changing the theme to Dark+ and it didn't make a difference either.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you set the `type` attribute in your script tag to `"text/jsx"` (nothing inherently wrong with that).

Currently (at the time of the writing, v1.75), VS Code only supports JavaScript intellisense for script tags with either no `type` attribute, or `type="module"`, `type="text/javascript"`, or `type="application/javascript"`, `type="text/babel"` or similar.

**`type="text/jsx"` is not currently supported, but `type="text/babel"` seems to support JSX.**

There have been two issues about this reported on the VS Code GitHub repo: [Syntax highlighting doesn't work with "text/jsx" script tags #150171](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150171) and [Syntax highlighting for text/jsx #145992](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145992). In both, the a repo maintainer comented that the correct place to report the issue is at https://github.com/textmate/html.tmbundle/issues, which has been done now: [Syntax for text/jsx inside HTML #119](https://github.com/textmate/html.tmbundle/issues/119). <sup><sub>Note: Please consider *not* commenting "me too" in the comments there. I can't speak for that repo's maintainers, but for many project maintainers, such comments tend to come off as annoying unless the commentor actually also volunteers to help out. You can just give a thumbs up reaction if you don't want to expend effort in helping implement the feature.</sub></sup>

For your skill-in-googling learning, here's the google search query I made to find those: `vscode issues html script jsx`

Related: [How can I enable IntelliSense for JavaScript inside HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37055382/11107541)

Comment: `type="text/babel"` works so **text/jsx** needs to inherit the same behaviour?

Comment: @DarrenEvans well... similar. JS and JSX are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use **type="text/babel"** instead of **type="text/jsx"** i.e,

```
<script type="text/babel">
    
     //your code here
     
</script>
```

That should solve the problem.