# [VSCode highlighting Problem]: JavaScript in the HTML file not getting highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow a [React Documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn/react-foundations/updating-state) for leaning ReactJS. 
While coding I came upon this problem. 
[image]

What should I do here to make the JavaScript part get highlighted? The code is working fine.

Comment: Is the `type="text/jsx"` needed? In my local environment removing that enabled highlighting.

Comment: This question is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421237/cant-get-the-correct-language-mode-intellisense-for-a-script-tag-with-type-t). But I could find it while searching. Mods, would you mark this question as duplicate or should I delete it?

Comment: You should put your JavaScript/jsx in to separate files.

Comment: Yes, I was just referring the steps given in the mentioned document!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `type=text/jsx` and you should be good

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just read **[this](https://github.com/textmate/html.tmbundle/issues/119)**! Thanks for the help!