# VS Code - IntelliSense for JavaScript/CSS inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055382/how-can-i-enable-intellisense-for-javascript-inside-html), which as of 2023 has a [solution](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_javascript-language-support-in-html), i.e. IntelliSense now works for `<script>` and `<style>` tags. That is, if the document mode is set to HTML.

[image: Screenshot]

However, I am currently working with a `.php` file (HTML with embedded PHP), so I need to use the PHP document mode for proper formatting and cannot simply switch to HTML. Unfortunately this seems to break IntelliSense for the `<script>` and `<style>` tags, as I am not getting the appropriate suggestions.

I have been searching for a solution for some time now, and could not solve this yet. Ideally, IntelliSense should work for HTML, PHP, JavaScript, and CSS in the same document depending on the context. If anyone has had this issue before and/or knows how I can get this to work it would be greatly appreciated.